# Как скорректировать функцию изменения кодировки из utf-8 в win1251? PHP

Tags: php, перекодировка, utf-8

Есть функция изменения кодировки из utf-8 в win1251.
Но заметил, что она неправильно перекодирует символы. Перекодирует символ "«" в "[", а "»" в "k"-латинскую. Например, из "«ТРА-ТА-ТА»" получается "[ТРА-ТА-ТАk".
Как скорректировать эту функцию? Или предложите другую работающую.

```
function utf2win( $str )
{
    $out= '';

    for( $c=0; $c < strlen( $str ); $c++ )
    {
        $i= ord( $str[ $c ] );

        if( $i <= 127 ) @$out .= $str[ $c ];

        if( @$byte2 )
        {
            $new_c2= ( $c1&3 ) * 64 + ( $i&63 );
            $new_c1= ( $c1 >> 2 )&5;
            $new_i= $new_c1 * 256 + $new_c2;
            $out_i= ( $new_i == 1025 ) ? 168 : ( ( $new_i == 1105 ) ? 184 : ( $new_i - 848 ) );
            @$out .= chr( $out_i );
            $byte2= false;
        }

        if( ( $i >> 5 ) == 6 )
        {
            $c1= $i;
            $byte2= true;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Обрезает полтекста. Не знаю по какой причине.

Надо было разобраться в причине, прежде чем велосипеды писать.

```
$string = @iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```

[`iconv()` — Преобразование строки в требуемую кодировку](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

> Если добавить к `out_charset` строку `//TRANSLIT`, включается режим транслитерации. Это значит, что в случае, если символ не может быть представлен в требуемой кодировке, он будет заменен на один или несколько нескольких наиболее близких по внешнему виду символов. Если добавить строку `//IGNORE`, то символы, которые не могут быть представлены в требуемой кодировке, будут удалены. **В случае отсутствия вышеуказанных параметров при наличии некорректных символов строка `str` будет обрезана до первого такого символа**, и будет сгенерирована ошибка уровня `E_NOTICE`.

P.S. На самом деле ошибка уровня `E_NOTICE` генерируется всегда, вне зависимости от наличия этих параметров, по этому использование @ (собачки) единственный способ сконвертировать строку без ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

```
ICONV("UTF-8","WINDOWS-1251",$STRING);
```

Зачем извращаться-то?

Comment: Некорректно работает.

Comment: Некорректно?

Приведи пример некорректной работы этой ф-и!

Comment: Обрезает полтекста. Не знаю по какой причине.

Comment: Я пример попросил, а не описание того что она что-то там обрезает.